# Python Function to Find Number of Days it Takes for a percent change to occur

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas dataframe of market price data.  It is the average trading price of a crypto currency (Ethereum) prices in USD.

I want to create a function that will take parameter, a percent amount. The idea is that the function will then output a integer where that integer represents the total number of days that it took for that percent increase to be seen.

Pandas has a function called `pct_change(periods=x)` which will tell you the percent change over a certain period.  I am basically looking for the opposite of this function.  How many day it took to reach a certain percent growth.

our dataframe:
df

```
index   ts  quote   base    last_bid
0   2015-08-07  USD ETH 3.000000
1   2015-08-08  USD ETH 1.266663
2   2015-08-09  USD ETH 1.266663
3   2015-08-10  USD ETH 1.266663
4   2015-08-11  USD ETH 1.026667
```

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import pandas as pd

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    ndf = df['last_bid'].pct_change(periods=index)
    print(ndf[ndf > .5])
```

This is giving me the every occurrence that each date performs over a 50% increase in price. However, I just want the First data where 50% is reached for each row. And then the loop will continue to the next row.

Ideally, All of this output would be in a single data frame with the same schema above. With 3 additional columns.  1.  The date where our percent gain occurred.  2. The actually percent change. 3. The date difference from between our start and end date.

Comment: This sounds super interesting, can't wait to see the solution!

Comment: More like a for loop problem . try do with `cumprod` :-)

Comment: Assuming that the _last\_bid_ on index 5 is 6.0. For index 0, the date difference would be 5 days. However, from index 1 onwards, the date difference will progressively shorten until you get 1 day at index 4, since the _last\_bid_ is less than half of that in index 0. Is this really what you want? It's not quite technically related to your question but I'm just curious about the usefulness of this analysis

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I am looking for. @kerwei

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not having access to exactly your data frame, this code downloads the data, reformats it to look more like yours, and then looks for changes of `target_percent` or more.

```
import csv

import requests
import pandas

from datetime import datetime, timedelta

url = 'https://etherscan.io/chart/etherprice?output=csv'

print "Downloading CSV"

r = requests.get(url)

with open("data.csv", "w") as csv_handle:
    csv_handle.write(r.text)

df = pandas.read_csv("data.csv")

# First reformat the etherscan data to look like the data frame in the question
print "Reformatting data"
df = df.drop(labels=["UnixTimeStamp"], axis=1)
df = df.rename(columns={'Date(UTC)': 'ts', 'Value' : 'last_bid'})
df['ts'] = df['ts'].str.replace('/', '-')
df['ts'].replace(to_replace='^(\d+-\d+)-(\d\d\d\d)$', value='\g<2>-\g<1>',inplace=True,regex=True)

# Now process the reformatted data frame

target_percent = 50

found_dates    = []
date_diffs     = []
actual_changes = []

for i in range(len(df)):
    found_date = "n/a"
    actual_change = "n/a"
    date_diff = "n/a"

    starting_date = df["ts"][i]
    starting_bid = df["last_bid"][i]

    for j in range(i+1, len(df)):
        if df["last_bid"][j] >= (1.0 + 0.01*target_percent) * starting_bid:
            actual_change = "{:.1f}%".format(100.0 * (df["last_bid"][j] / starting_bid) - 100.0)
            found_date    = df["ts"][j]
            date_diff = str(datetime.strptime(found_date, "%Y-%m-%d") - datetime.strptime(starting_date, "%Y-%m-%d")).split(",")[0]
            break


    date_diffs.append(date_diff)
    actual_changes.append(actual_change)
    found_dates.append(found_date)

df["found_date"] = found_dates
df["actual_change"] = actual_changes
df["date_diff"] = date_diffs

print df
```

It gives screwy results for the first few records, with a price of zero, but looks okay after that:

```
Downloading CSV
Reformatting data
           ts  last_bid found_date actual_change date_diff
1   2015-7-31      0.00   2015-8-1          nan%     1 day
2    2015-8-1      0.00   2015-8-2          nan%     1 day
3    2015-8-2      0.00   2015-8-3          nan%     1 day
4    2015-8-3      0.00   2015-8-4          nan%     1 day
5    2015-8-4      0.00   2015-8-5          nan%     1 day
6    2015-8-5      0.00   2015-8-6          nan%     1 day
7    2015-8-6      0.00   2015-8-7          inf%     1 day
8    2015-8-7      2.77  2016-2-10         57.0%  187 days
9    2015-8-8      0.81  2015-8-12         54.3%    4 days
10   2015-8-9      0.74  2015-8-12         68.9%    3 days
11  2015-8-10      0.68  2015-8-11         55.9%     1 day
12  2015-8-11      1.06  2015-8-13         67.9%    2 days
13  2015-8-12      1.25  2016-1-23         62.4%  164 days
14  2015-8-13      1.78   2016-2-7         68.5%  178 days
15  2015-8-14      1.79   2016-2-7         67.6%  177 days
16  2015-8-15      1.79   2016-2-7         67.6%  176 days
17  2015-8-16      1.37  2016-1-24         53.3%  161 days
```

Comment: This is absolutely what I was trying to do.  This is working perfectly for me.  I have data from a different source from exchange API's but the function works exactly as I needed! Thanks YOU RULE!